# axiom of choice Zorn's lemma

Tags: set-theory

In Naive Set Theory, on page 65, Paul Halmos asks to show that Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the axiom of choice. The exact statement of the question is given below:

Exercise. Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the axiom of choice. [Hint for the proof: given a set $X$, consider function $f$ such that $dom f\subset\mathcal{P}(X),ran f\subset X$, and $f(A)\in A$ for all $A$ in $dom f$; order these functions by extension, use Zorn's lemma to find a maximal one among them, and prove that if $f$ is maximal, then $dom f=\mathcal{P}(X)-\{\emptyset\}$.]

I have followed the hint and proved that the mentioned set has a maximal element $f$. I also need to show that $dom f=\mathcal{P}(X)-\{\emptyset\}$. I could not do this last step. My reasoning as follows: if the domain of $f$ is not $\mathcal{P}(X)-\{\emptyset\}$, then there must be a nonempty subset of X, say $O$, not included in $dom f$. Then, to find a contradiction, we should be able to extend $f$ such that the domain of the new function $g$ will include $O$. Then, I need to show that it is possible to have $g(O)\in O$. Since $O$ is not empty, there exists an $x\in O$ and I set $g(O)=x$. Does this last step use the axiom of choice and is this proof correct?

Comment: Could you phrase your question in a way such that one could understand it without having to go look at Halmos' book?

Comment: Please state the problem as is, seeing that a lot of people do not have this book.

Comment: No, picking a single element from a single nonempty set is Existential Instantiation, and does not require the Axiom of Choice. You have a proof by contrapositive that a  function of the type in question with domain *not* equal to $\mathcal{P}(X)-\{\varnothing\}$ is not maximal, which is equivalent to what you want to prove.

Comment: Clarification: "No" is meant to be answering "No, you arenot using the axiom of choice". Yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: @Ruy, I have added the exact statement of the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: @algevristis, I have added the exact statement of the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: In order for curly brackets to "show up" in MathJax, you must precede then with a backslash: `$-\{\text{stuff}\}-$` will produce $-\{\text{stuff}\}-$.  Whereas `$-{\text{stuff}}-$` produces $-{\text{stuff}}-$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes your proof is correct.  The fact that $O$ is non-empty allows you to pick an element there and for this you do not need the axiom of choice.  The subtlety behind the AC is that it allows you to choose infinitely many elements at once (the *choice function*), while picking one by one would take an infinitely long time.

Comment: "Choosing" $x=g(O)\in O$ means asserting there exists an ordered pair $(O,x)$ with $x\in O,$ which does not need AC.